# How to count values between empty cells

Tags: awk

I'm facing one problem which is bigger than me. I have 18 relative large text files (ca 30k lines each) and I need to count the values between the empty cells in the second column. Here is a simple example of my file:

```
Metabolism
line_1    10.2
line_2    10.1
line_3    10.3
TCA_cycle
line_4    10.7
line_5    10.8
Pyruvate_metab
line_6   100.8
```

In reality, I have circa 500 description lines (Metabolism, TCA_cycle, etc.) and the range of lines is between zero to a few hundred.

I would like to count values for each block (block starts with a description and corresponding lines are always below), e.g.

```
Metabolism  30.6
line_1    10.2
line_2    10.1
line_3    10.3
TCA_cycle   21.5
line_4    10.7
line_5    10.8
Pyruvate_metab 100.8
line_6   100.8
```

Or just

```
30.3
21.5
100.8
```

It won't be a problem if results will be printed line by line into an additional file... Or another alternative way.

There is one tricky thing and it's descriptions without lines with numbers.

```
Transport
line_1000   100.1
line_1001   100.2
Cell_signal
Motility
Processing
Translation
line_1002   500.1
line_1003   200.2
```

And even for those lines and would like to get 0 value.

```
Transport     200.3
line_1000   100.1
line_1001   100.2
Cell_signal   0
Motility      0
Processing    0
Translation   700.3
line_1002   500.1
line_1003   200.2
```

The rest of the file looks same and it's consistent - 2 columns, tab separators, descriptions in the first column, values in the second, no spaces (only underlines).

Actually I have no experience with more sophisticated coding so I really don't know how to solve it in the command line. I've already tried some Excel ways but it was painful and unsuccessful.

Comment: How is the 30.3 calculated?

Comment: how do you differentiate "descriptions without lines" from the block headers?

Comment: @Cyrus sorry, my fail - not 30.3 but 30.6...

Comment: @Cyrus I believe that was [alternative math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh3Yz3PiXZw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `tac` and any `awk`:

```
tac file | awk 'NF==2{sum+=$2; print; next} {print $1 "\t" sum; sum=0}' | tac
```

---

With two improvements proposed by [kvantour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8344060/kvantour) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton). See the comments.

```
tac file | awk '($NF+0==$NF){sum+=$2; print; next} {print $1 "\t" sum+0; sum=0}' | tac
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0!~/line/){  a[$0]; prev=$0 }
  else          {  a[prev]+=$NF   }
  next
}
!/line/{
  $0=$0 OFS (a[$0]?a[$0]:0)
}
1'  Input_file  Input_file
```

OR in case you want output in good looking form add `column -t` to above command like as follows:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0!~/line/){  a[$0]; prev=$0 }
  else          {  a[prev]+=$NF   }
  next
}
!/line/{
  $0=$0 OFS (a[$0]?a[$0]:0)
}
1'  Input_file  Input_file  |  column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                        ##Checking FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file is being read first time.
  if($0!~/line/){  a[$0]; prev=$0 }             ##checking condition if line contains string line and setting index of current line in a and setting prev value to current line.
  else          { a[prev]+=$NF    }             ##Else if line not starting from line then creating array a with index prev variable and keep on adding last field value to same index of array.
  next                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!/line/{                                        ##Checking if current line doesnot have line keyword in it then do following.
  $0=$0 OFS (a[$0]?a[$0]:0)                     ##Re-creating current line with its current value then OFS(which is space by default) then either add value of a[$0] or 0 based on current line value is NOT NULL here.
}
1                                               ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 3):

In plain `awk`:

```
awk '{
    if (NF == 1) {
        if (blockname)
            printf("%s\t%.2f\n%s", blockname, sum, lines)
        blockname = $0
        sum = 0
        lines=""
    } else if (NF == 2) {
        sum += $2 
        lines = lines $0 "\n"
    }
    next
}
END { printf("%s\t%.2f\n%s", blockname, sum, lines) }
' input.txt
```